# Sobolev spaces on Riemannian manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I know one can define the Sobolev spaces on a Riemannian manifold as completions, but is there an equivalent definition that uses weak derivatives, like in the case of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Thanks

Comment: Intrinisc colocal weak derivatives?     http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5858.pdf

Comment: Sure, pick a bunch of charts and use a partition of unity to do the standard thing.